# Replace single quote / apostrophe in NTEXT column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, replace

I have an `NTEXT` column in a table, having XML tag data with single quotes. I have to replace strings having XML tag data and quote quote with blank.

I have data in col as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> <securesite>   <content>     <formsections>       <version>12</version>       <introduction>         <p>Based on the product </p>         <p>If you are registered for  </p>     <p>                     <![CDATA[         **<p><b>Can't see your form in the list below</b></p>**         <a href="http://www.testcom.aspx" target="_blank" alt="View forms">View forms</a>         ]]>                 </p><.....
```

I have to remove string

```
<p><b>Can't see your form in the list below</b></p>
```

I have tried using the following query, but it did not worked:

```
UPDATE Table SET Col = REPLACE( Col, '  <p><b>Can't see your form in the list below</b></p>  ', '')
```

Also tried single quote replaces as `''''` single quote:

```
UPDATE Table SET Col = REPLACE( Col, '  <p><b>Can''''t see your form in the list below</b></p>  ', '')
```

I also tried this:

```
UPDATE Table SET Col =REPLACE( CAST( col as varchar(max) ), '  <p><b>Can''''t see your form in the list below</b></p>  ', '')
```

Also tried as adviced

```
DECLARE @YourOriginalText NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @YourModifiedText NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @YourOriginalText = CAST(Col AS NVARCHAR(MAX))FROM [Table]
SET @YourModifiedText = REPLACE( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Col), N'  <p><b>Can''t see     your form in the list below</b></p>  ', '')
SELECT @YourModifiedText

UPDATE [Table] SET Col= CAST(@YourModifiedText AS NTEXT)
```

but it didn't worked too.

Can you guide me in the right direction and show me how to replace the text?

Comment: Have you tried `SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An escaped single-quote is two single-quotes, not four. Also, NTEXT does not seem to work with the `REPLACE` function as you get the following error:

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Argument data type ntext is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

So, try this (`NTEXT` cannot be compared with `=` so you need to use `LIKE`):

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET Col = N''
WHERE Col LIKE N'  <p><b>Can''t see your form in the list below</b></p>  ';
```

**OR**, convert the column to NVARCHAR(MAX) so that it does work with the `REPLACE` function:

```
UPDATE [Table]
SET Col =
   REPLACE( CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX), Col),
            N'  <p><b>Can''t see your form in the list below</b></p>  ',
             '');
```

(the above query is essentially your 3rd attempt, but has the embedded single-quote properly escaped)

In both cases, since it is an `NTEXT` field, you should be prefixing string literals with a capital-"N" as well as casting / converting to `NVARCHAR` rather than `VARCHAR`.

Comment: I have tried as per your sugestion I have edited my query in the above post. Please check and help me..

Comment: @user3540425 : please be more specific about what didn't work. Did you get an error or what? I tested my query and it does what was expected. I even did a CONVERT(NTEXT, @NVarcharMaxVariable) and it worked as expected. I also don't see a FROM clause in your new `SET @YourModifiedText = REPLACE(` query, so how does that not error?

Comment: @user3540425 : Also, you don't need to CAST / CONVERT back into NTEXT. It will be done implicitly. Just use the 2nd query that I posted, exactly as I have it and it should work. There is no need to break it out into multiple steps. But, if "it didn't work" means that it just didn't replace the text, then that is another issue and requires looking at the exact text in your column. Maybe there are newlines that you aren't seeing due to using `SELECT @YourOriginalText` instead of `PRINT @YourOriginalText`?